# Which ROS2 release works on the Jetson TX2?

Tags: ros2, ubuntu, ubuntu-xenial, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are currently four versions of ROS2. However I don't understand which version is explicitly for Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial) on the Jetson TX2. Am I able to use ros-kinetic in conjunction with one of the ROS2 releases? Where is the documentation regarding installation of ros2 on a tx2?

Update:
I've found a link to installing ROS2, which is below:
https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Crystal/Linux-Install-Debians/

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/324676/which-ros2-release-works-on-the-jetson-tx2?/) by [StewartHemm74](https://answers.ros.org/users/39655/stewarthemm74/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2019-06-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-04**:\

> Where is the documentation regarding installation of ros2 on a tx2?

Slightly pedantic, but just curious: what makes you expect there is documentation available for this particular combination?

**Comment by [StewartHemm74](https://answers.ros.org/users/39655/stewarthemm74/) on 2019-06-04**:
I found documentation installing ROS1 (kinetic, groovy, etc.) on a jetson tx1 or tx2. Also there are several youtube videos showing proper installation of ROS. However, I haven't found as much information on ROS2.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-04**:
All of that is community contributed. Probably personal, but since you wrote "where is *the* documentation" I understood that as meaning: "where is the official documentation".

**Comment by [MrCheesecake](https://answers.ros.org/users/44078/mrcheesecake/) on 2020-04-22**:
for future readers: you can find the supported processor architectures and operating systems and if there are prebuild packages for the combination for each ROS2 version under this link: https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-2000.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ros2 crystal is the last release to officially support Ubuntu 16.04. If you use crystal, you'll have to build it from source (hence tier 2 support) to work on the TX2.

You can run ros kinetic along-side ros2, but for them to talk to each other at all, you'll have to use the ros1-bridge. That'll let you bridge ros1->ros2 and ros2->ros1.

---

Originally posted by [ChuiV](https://answers.ros.org/users/30013/chuiv/) with karma: 1046 on 2019-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1